# My ubuntu wont boot after i shut it down

Tags: boot, init, initramfs

I shut down my laptop one night and moved it. It was working fine before I shut it down. The next day I try to turn it on and I got this.

```
No init found. Try passing init= bootarg.

BusyBox v1.13.3 (Ubuntu 1:1.13.3-1ubuntu11) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

I dont know what happened. I tried every help command but nothing helped. Some just froze my computer. What do I do to fix it? (I don't know much about computers so the simplest way would be appreciated though if I need to I'll learn more.)

Answer (score 0):

Do you still have your live boot media? If so, try this:

1. Boot into the media (CD, flash drive)
2. Make sure your hard drive is not mounted, the simplest way to do this is:

   1. Open up the file manager (`nautilus`) and see if your hard drive is mounted on the left
   2. If it is, unmount all of the partitions on it by right-clicking them and choosing unmount
3. Open a terminal and type

   `sudo fsck /dev/sda1`

You may need to try that two or three times, from what I'm seeing from a google search.